# QTM & Halting problem

Tags: turing-machines, quantum-computing

"Can QTM (Quantum Turing machine) solve halting problem"
Why not have an immediate answer "No QTM Can't do this", we know that Turing proved it impossible when DTM , i meant , " Why we cant use the same proof which turing use it"
Let H be a program in a quantum turing machine that will solve the issue of halting , why not say that a contradiction will occur 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we can simulate QTM with DTM and it is an easier proof method than proving directly for QTM (which we can do). Also, this method of simulating a model with DTM to prove they are equivalent in power is somewhat a standard tool, not just for various TMs, but also for other computaitonal models ($\lambda$-calculus, RAM-machines,$\ldots$)

I think this question and answers address everything else you may be wondering

- [References on comparison between quantum computers and Turing machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6296/references-on-comparison-between-quantum-computers-and-turing-machines)

Comment: I understand from your answer, it can not and  DTM equivalent QTM, Right?? Thanks sir @sandro

Comment: Yes, QTM cannot solve Halting problem and QTM is computationaly equivalent to DTM, i.e. both can compute the same class of functions - partial recursive functions.